# Can't send a message when the first word of a sentence is specified

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot. I have a done a ping function when the bot answers pong. This a properly working. But now i am trying to make a music bot so the command is `~play url`
I'm taking the first word of the command to be sure it's `~play`. But my way to analyze the sentence is not correct apparently.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log('I am ready!');
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '~ping') {  
    message.reply('pong');
  }  
  var msg = message.content;
  var play = msg.split(" ", 1);
  if (play === '~play') {
    console.log('jioejfaoi');
  }
});


client.login('mytoken');
```

Answer (score 0):

The `split` function returns an array, even if it has only one value.

```
var play = msg.split(" ", 1)[0]
```

Comment: `"~play music".split(" ", 1)` would return an array: `["~play"]`. the `[0]` means you only want the first element of this array.